# How to get names list from json array using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have json like

```
[
  {
    "name": "xx",
    "address": "Ch"
  },
  {
    "name": "yy",
    "address": "Ch"
  },
  {
    "name": "zz",
    "address": "TRY"
  }
]
```

I want result like

```
var names=["xx","yy","zz"]
```

But do not use looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jsonQ http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html

```
var list=[
  {
    "name": "xx",
    "address": "Ch"
  },
  {
    "name": "yy",
    "address": "Ch"
  },
  {
    "name": "zz",
    "address": "TRY"
  }
];
var names=jsonQ(list).find("name").value();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var names = json.map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = json.map(item => item.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

var names = jQuery.parseJSON( json_object );

may be you don't need a loop but still you have to import this famous js liabrary. and may be there's a loop in that source code(I dont know what's in there)